# spring-context XSD schema can't be found in jar after adding spring-tx dependency

Tags: java, spring, xsd, applicationcontext, spring-4

I have an stand-alone java application which is built by gradle and running from jar archive.
When I run it from eclipse, everything is fine. When I run it from command-line I get an exception that it can't be found spring-context.xsd file.

This problem begins after I added spring-tx dependency to my application.

The exception message:

```
D:\docs>java -jar WebserverMinimal.jar
DEBUG: me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain - app started
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinit
ionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHan
dler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [context-test.xml]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.err
or(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderC
ontext.java:85)
...
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain.main(SelfcareMain.java:15)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'     
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'     
version = '1.0'     
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

task createJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = "WebserverMinimal.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example', 
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'me.test.selfcare.SelfcareMain'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

task copyJarToBin {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'build/libs/WebserverMinimal.jar'
            into "d:/docs"
        }
    }
}
copyJarToBin.mustRunAfter createJar

task buildWebserver (dependsOn: [clean, createJar, copyJarToBin])

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.9'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.9'

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.7.RELEASE'
}
```

As I said the problem begins after adding this dependency:

> compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.7.RELEASE'

When I start to compare gradle dependencies for working and not working version the only difference what I found is

```
\--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.7.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
```

But spring-core and spring-beans are also been added before with these versions.

I checked the jar file and found in META-INF spring.schemas, spring.handlers and spring.tooling files from the spring-context.jar. So there's mapping to **existing** in jar xsd

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
```

I can't figure out why is this exception occurred. Could you help me?

How I try to initialize application context:

```
public class SelfcareMain {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SelfcareMain.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        log.debug("app started");
        String contextName="classpath:context-test.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextName);
        log.debug("spring context is initialized");
    }

}
```

context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

Comment: And how is this executable jar getting the dependencies? Is everything packaged in the jar? Like with the maven-shade plugin? If so make sure that all the `spring.handler` files etc. are merged into a large one instead of overwriting them..

Comment: You're right. If I merge each for spring.handlers, spring.schemas and spring.tooling from several to one file, everything will be fine. I'll try to figure out how to configure build.gradle for this merging